# Is there a way (e.g. an extension) to avoid Google Chrome from saving a specific site to the History?

Tags: google-chrome, history, privacy

I use to visit erotic websites, and I would like those websites to not be logged to the browser's history (so I don't have to always removing them manually), is there a way?

I believe I can just turn off the whole browser history. But is there a way to turn it off just for some websites?

Comment: It might be possible to write a Chrome extension that would periodically remove web pages from specific domains. That would require some knowledge of Javascript, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Chrome has an incognito mode, which means none of the history or activity is saved for a tab:

- Webpages that you open and files downloaded while you are incognito aren't recorded in your browsing and download histories.
- All new cookies are deleted after you close all incognito windows that you've opened.
- Changes made to your Google Chrome bookmarks and general settings while in incognito mode are always saved.

<sup>You can read more about this at the support page: [Incognito mode (browse in private)](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95464)</sup>

#### Start an Incognito Tab:

To start an incognito tab either use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>, or click the spanner icon and select `New Incognito Tab`.

Answer (score 3):

To build on Paul's answer, if you want to enter incognito mode by default and you're using Windows, you can modify your Chrome shortcut's target adding `--incognito`.

#### For example:

```
C:\<your path>\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --incognito
```

Just update `<your path>` with wherever Chrome is installed locally and You'll be incognito whenever you start up your Chrome browser with the modified shortcut.

#### Manually cear History:

As a follow-on, you can also manually clear Chrome's history with any of the following options:

- Hitting <kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>
- Click the Chrome menu [image] on the browser toolbar:

  1. Select "Tools".
  2. Select "Clear browsing data".
  3. In the dialog that appears, select the "Clear browsing history" checkbox.
  4. Use the menu at the top to select the amount of data you want to delete.
  5. Click the button "Clear browsing data".

<sup>You can read more about this at the support page: [Delete your browsing history](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95537)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

There is a Google Chrome extension called [History Site Blocker](http://www.addictivetips.com/internet-tips/disable-history-for-certain-websites-in-chrome-history-site-blocker/) that is designed to do exactly this: preventing specific websites from being saved to web history.

Answer (score 0):

Browser extension "[History Blacklist](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-blacklist/dglhdhjfhaikplcgklplalmejcahjheo)". You specify sites that do not need to be saved to history, and they are not saved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).