# Filter specific websites from web history

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way (e.g. an extension) to avoid Google Chrome from saving a specific site to the History?](https://superuser.com/questions/352959/is-there-a-way-e-g-an-extension-to-avoid-google-chrome-from-saving-a-specific)

Is it possible to automatically filter specific websites or web pages from web history in Google Chrome? For instance, would it be possible to stop web pages from www.youtube.com, or en.wikipedia.org, from being stored in web history?

Comment: Sounds exactly what Incognito Mode is for.

Comment: @AlEverett Yes, but Incognito Mode doesn't automatically filter specific websites from a user's web history. That's the type of feature that I'm trying to find.

Comment: Then, no, it doesn't appear to be possible. You can either prevent writing to web history altogether (Incognito) or scrub particular entries out of your web history after the fact.

Comment: @AlEverett Specifically, I'd like to "scrub particular web entries after the fact" using a Google Chrome extension. I could perhaps write such an extension myself, if no one has created it already. Then, of course, I'd need to know whether it's possible for Chrome extensions to access and modify web history.